# Allow users to set higher (lower?) nice levels

Tags: 12.04, permissions, nice

I want to allow users to set a `nice`level lower than 0 (and any `nice` level really) in my system. I'm testing by logging in again as a user of the affected user group after I set the change and trying:

```
nice -n -18 sleep 1
```

Which keeps producing the message:

```
nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied
```

I also check `ulimit -a` which doesn't change after saving my changes in `limits.conf`.

I have tried reading some google results. And came up with this in my `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
@mygroup   soft    nice    -20
@mygroup   hard    nice    18
```

I also tried the reverse, since nice is reversed (so `hard -20` and `soft 18`), which didn't work.

As some google results suggested I made sure the line:

```
session    required   pam_limits.so
```

Is not commented in my `/etc/pam.d/login` file (it wasn't when I first checked).

Any suggestions how to enable this?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 precise.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up firing up a server I could mess around with more and I tried more combinations. I couldn't get `hard` or `soft` to play nice (get it?), so I tried `-` and it worked. I also confirmed with Ubuntu 14.04 trusty.

I figured `-` sets hard **and** soft limits:

```
 @mygroup   -    nice    -20
```

This does work once you log on and off. You won't see any entry regarding `nice` in `ulimit -a`. What you should be looking for is:

```
scheduling priority             (-e) 40
```

Which `nice` later on probably treats as [-20 19]. The default value for this entry is 0.

Using dash seems to enable **any priority**. So if anyone can get `hard` and `soft` to work drop a comment or an answer. Thanks.